# Add datafactory project in visual studio for version2 of ADF

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

As we can add Data Factory project for ADF version1. Can we add project for ADF version2 and if yes how can we do that? Whenever I am trying to add Data Factory Project it gives me option for version1 and not for version2. Is there anyway to add ADF version2 project to my solution?

Answer (score 0):

Things have changed when we talk & work on ADF V1 and V2. I am presuming when you are saying `ADFV1` project in `VS` you used to create empty project for data integration solution where you had to create `linked services`, `datasets` & `pipelines` based on the defined template - `json` format.

Now from `ADFV2` on wards if you want to code `ADFV2` in `C#` you can simply create a `console application` and code your way through `ADFV2`. Likewise if you choose other programming methods the way to do it changes.

For more detailed reference please have a look at the complete [ADFV2 documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/opbuildpdf/data-factory/TOC.pdf?branch=live).

Comment: When I say ADFV1 project, we get a option to add DataFactory project while adding new project. Not an empty project. So the same DataFactory project is available for ADFV2 or not?